# ¿Cual es la diferencia en git de rm file y reset hard?

Tags: git

Estoy comenzando en el mundo de la programacion pero tengo una duda que diferencia existe entre `rm "file"` y `git reset hard`

Comment: rm es del sistema operativo, git reset es propio de git

Answer (score 1):

En principio no tienen nada qué ver una con la otra.

`rm` (sin `git` delante) es una orden del shell. Borra un archivo sin más. Si el archivo no estaba bajo control de versiones, `git` no lo echará de menos (de hecho dejará de indicarte que el archivo no está bajo control de versiones, pues ha dejado de existir). Si en cambio estaba bajo control de versiones, `git` te avisará de que ha desaparecido, dándote la opción de recuperarlo o de eliminarlo también del repositorio.

`git rm` indica a `git` que ese archivo (que debía estar bajo control de versiones) deje de estarlo y además lo borre del disco. Sería la forma correcta de borrar un archivo de la carpeta de trabajo a la vez que lo quitas del repositorio. No obstante es frecuente cometer el error de borrarlo con `rm` a secas, para después darse cuenta de que se debía haber usado `git rm`. En este caso no pasa nada, pues puedes hacer el `git rm` después (aún si el fichero ya no existe) para que `git` deje de echarlo de menos.

Después de un `git rm` es necesario hacer un *commit* para que ese cambio quede registrado en el histórico del repositorio. Por cierto que eso no borra el fichero de los *commits* previos en los que ya aparecía, pero al menos cuando cualquier otra persona haga un `git clone` para obtener la última versión, no obtendrá ese fichero en su carpeta de trabajo (aunque si hace `checkout` a versiones previas podría obtenerlo, por lo que no es una forma de borrarlo "del todo").

Finalmente `git reset` es una forma de hacer que una rama "retroceda" a un commit pasado. Si a partir de ese punto vuelves a hacer `commit`s nuevos, éstos "sobreescribirían" (por así decir) los que tenía la rama original a partir de ese punto. No conviene hacerlo si tu repositorio está compartido con otros, pues estás sobreescribiendo la historia de una rama y eso causará problemas a otras personas que pueden perder trabajo si habían estado desarrollando en la misma rama.

`git reset --hard` además de retroceder la rama, actualiza la carpeta de trabajo eliminando todas las modificaciones que se hubieran hecho en todos los ficheros a partir del commit indicado, y eliminando los ficheros creados desde entonces. Es decir, la carpeta de trabajo quedará tal como estaba en aquel commit. Es un comando peligroso que puede hacerte perder trabajo. Úsalo sólo si estás seguro de lo que haces.

Comment: Agradecería a quien me ha puntuado negativo me explique cuál es el error de mi respuesta. Lo digo sin acritud, y con el ánimo de aprender o de retirar la respuesta si es que era errónea.

Answer (score 0):

> `git reset --hard` : Elimina todos los cambios/modificaciones que se hicieron después del ultimo `commit`.

#### Ejemplo:

Tienes un archivo `index.html`, a las `4:53pm` y el ultimo `commit` es 'primer cambio' así:

```html
  index.html 4:53pm commit #ab575... 'primer cambio'
  + <head></head>
  + <body></body>
```

Durante unos 10 minutos de trabajo agregas una lineas y otro nuevo `commit`.

```html
   index.html 4:60pm commit #ab896... 'segundo cambio'
   + <head></head>
   + <body>
   +   <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
   + </body>
```

Ahora si ejecutas el comando `git reset --hard` , tu archivo `index.html` quedara así.

```html
   index.html 4:53pm commit #ab575... 'primer cambio' 
   + <head></head>
   + <body></body>
```

Regresas tu archivo en el tiempo (vuelve a estar a las 4:53) y perdiendo todos los cambios que realizaste.

> `git rm "file"` : Elimina el archivo especificado para no ser observado con el control de versiones. ( este tendrá dos comportamientos distintos segundo si el archivo solo esta observado por `git status` o si esta en `cache` osea ya se realizo un `commit` con este archivo ) os mostrare el caso mas común.

#### Ejemplo:

Tienes tu archivo index.html, recuerda que esta con el `commit` de las 4:53, ahora quieres agregar algo de estilo entonces agregas un `<link>` para un nuevo archivo `main.css`.

```html
  index.html 4:53pm commit #ab575... 'primer cambio'
  + <head><link src="./main.css"></link></head>
  | <body></body>
```

Crear un nuevo archivo para los estilos llamado `main.css`

```css
  main.css 5:00pm
  + head { color: red; }
```

Ejecutas primero el comando `git status`.

```yaml
  # Changes not staged for commit:
    M  index.html +1
  # no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
    N  main.css +1
```

Te darás cuenta que salen secciones, la primera con los archivos que le haz echo `commit` y salen precedidos por una `M` que significa `modificados` y los que nos haz agregado todavía, salen con una `N` que significa `nuevos`.  Aun el comando `git rm` no tiene accion aqui sobre `main.css` , primero debo agregarlo con `git add main.css` como se recomienda en la linea `# no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")`.  Si ejecuto el comando queda y luego de nuevo `git status` queda asi.

```sh
  $ git add main.css
  $ git status

  # Changes not staged for commit:
    M  index.html +1
    N  main.css +1
  # no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Ahora el archivo `main.css` paso de estar abajo a estar arriba, si después me arrepiento de usar este archivo porque voy a usar por ejemplo `bootstrap.min.css` entonces **ese es el caso donde debo usar el git rm**, para volver a pasar el archivo de arriba a abajo y no ser agregado al control de versiones.

```
  $ git rm main.css
  $ git status

  # Changes not staged for commit:
    M  index.html +1
  # no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
    N  main.css +1
    N  bootstrap.min.css +1
```

Ahora ya el archivo `main.css` esta de nuevo en la parte inferior junto con el otro nuevo archivo `bootstrap.min.css` paso a seguir subir `bootstrap..` y hacer commit. Te imaginaras entonces los comandos.

```
  $ git add bootstrap.min.css
  $ git commit -m "tercer cambio"
```

quedado así entonces:

```
  # 5:20pm commit #ac456... 'tercer cambio'
    index.html 
    bootstrap.min.css

  # 4:53pm commit #ab575... 'primer cambio'
    index.html
```

Así se pudo remover el archivo `main.css` para que no sea agregado a los cambios.